# Masking multiple columns on a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, dataframe, mask

I am looking to apply multiply masks on each column of a pandas dataset (respectively to its properties) in Python.

In the next step, I want to find (a) row(s) in the dataframe that fits all conditions.

Therefore I have:

```
df
Out[27]:
   DE  FL  GA  IA  ID
0   0   1   0   0   0
1   1   0   1   0   1
2   0   0   1   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0

mask_list = []
for i in range(0,5):

    if i % 2==0:
        mask_list.append(df[[i]]>0)
    else:
        mask_list.append(df[[i]]<1)

concat_frame = pa.DataFrame()
for mask in mask_list:
    concat_frame =pa.concat((concat_frame, mask), axis=1)

concat_frame
Out[48]:
      DE     FL     GA    IA     ID
0  False   False False  True  False
1  True    True  True   True  True
2  False   True  True   True  False
3  False   False False  True  False
4  False   True  False  True  False

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

Expected outcome:

```
Out[60]:
   DE   FL  GA  IA  ID
1   1   0   1   0   1
```

How can I apply the *concat_mask* on *df*, so that I *select rows*, in which all Boolean criteria are matched (are True)?

Comment: What is the expected output, none of your rows are all True, only 'IA' as a column has all True values

Comment: @EdChum thank You for Your comment. I added the expected outomce

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the pandas *[all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)* method and Boolean logic. As [EdChum commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328650/masking-multiple-columns-on-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python#comment37607883_24328650), I am a bit unclear still on your exact example, but a similar example is:

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame([[1,2],[-3,5]], index=[0,1], columns=['a','b'])
In [2]: df
Out [2]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1 -3  5

In [3]: msk = (df>1) & (df<5)
In [4]: msk
Out [4]:
      a    b
0 False  True
1 False False

In [5]: msk.all(axis=1)
Out [5]:
0  False
1  False
dtype: bool
```

If you wanted to index the original dataframe by the mask you could do:

```
In [6]: df[msk]
Out [6]:
     a   b
0  NaN   2
1  NaN NaN
```

Or as you originally indicated, rows where all the rows are true:

```
In [7]: idx = msk.all(axis=1)
In [8]: df[idx]
Out [8]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a,b]
Index: []
```

Or if one row was true

```
In [9]: idx[0] = True
In [10]: df[idx]
Out [10]:
  a b
0 1 2
```

For the original question after clarification from the comments, where we want different filtering criteria for different columns:

```
In [10]: msk1 = df[['a']] < 0
In [11]: msk2 = df[['b']] > 3
In [12]: msk = concat((msk1, msk2), axis=1)
In [12]: slct = msk.all(axis=1)
In [13]: df.ix[slct]
Out [13]:
   a b
1 -3 5
```

Comment: thank You that helped. I wanted to do:
index = s_mask.all(axis=1)
select = df.ix[index]
out:
Out[21]: 
   a  b
1 -3  5
. Can You insert that into your answer? Then i will marked it as answered :)

Comment: Not exactly sure I undersand, if I do the above I would get an empty dataframe since index is False for both rows, does your s_mask refer to msk in my example? so I'm unsure how your getting Out[21] as in your comment?

Comment: oh yes, i jumped ahead there. I applied:
msk1 = df[[0]]<0
msk2 = df[[1]]>3
s_mask = pandas.concat((msk1, msk2), axis=1)

Comment: Hey @Antihead let me know if that last edit addressed your concern

Comment: General caution for combining masks: Not immediately obvious to me initially is that because of precedence rules, combining masks using the operators `&` and `|`, requires the individual relational expressions to be parenthesised because of precedence rules, otherwise you either get errors, or worse misleading, crazy bitwise-op'ed results because `&` and `|` have higher precedence than the relational ops! (ref: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df[['DE', 'GA', 'ID']].all(axis=1) * (1 - df[['FL', 'IA']]).all(axis=1)]
```

The hard part here is understanding why you're using even/odd column positions to determine the treatment. Based on your code, it looks like you want columns 0, 2, and 4 to actually be 1 minus their current values. However, based on what you claim is the expected output, it actually seems like you want colums 1 and 3 to have 1 minus their current values.

My code above reflects the latter assumption. The general idea still works; just tune it to reflect whatever columns you actually need to have 1 minus the value of, assuming you make your desired output more rigorously defined.

Probably that needs to be cleaned up and turned into a proper helper function first that explicitly shows which columns need to have 1 minus their value, versus which columns can be left alone.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. In the proper code i actually iterate throw all columns and apply various of diffenrent conditions to mask each column. This is all what the code ment to express.
And i actually want to extract data of the original df dataframe....

Comment: The approach that I give does extract the data from the original DataFrame as needed.